# Codeigniter saving unique page views

Tags: codeigniter

What's the best way to count and them add to a total in my database the unique views of a page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fields--    userid      page
data--      testuser    index.php/whatever/
```

Add userid and page in database.

If the testuser visits that page again, don't add. However, if he visits a different page, add that information into db again.

Same with all users and pages.